# SQL passing table column to a function parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, function, parameters

I wish to call my function (`dbo.Split`) with a column table (`U.UbicacionF`) but it doesn't work! Please can u help me!! Thanks

```
SELECT 
    EE.IDEstatus, EE.IDAsignacion,EE.IDUNIDAD, 
    EE.IDEQUIPO,EE.ESTATUS,EE.bUltEstatus, 
    A.IDDestino, U.UbicacionF, TI.Tiempo 
FROM 
    mar_EstatusEquipo EE 
LEFT JOIN 
    mar_Asignaciones A ON EE.IDAsignacion = A.IDAsignacion 
                       AND EE.IDUNIDAD = A.IDUNIDAD
LEFT JOIN 
    mar_TmpUbicaciones U ON EE.IDUNIDAD = U.IdUnidad AND U.IdUnidad = A.IDUNIDAD
LEFT JOIN 
    mar_TiemposArriboPto TI ON A.IDDestino = TI.Destino 
                            AND TI.Ubicacion LIKE '%' + (SELECT * 
                                                         FROM dbo.Split(U.UbicacionF, ',', '1')) + '%' 
WHERE 
    EE.IDEquipo = CAST(EE.IDUNIDAD AS CHAR)
    AND EE.Estatus IN ('IT','ET')
    AND A.IDDestino = 'MZO'
    AND EE.bUltEstatus = 1
    AND EE.IDUNIDAD = 255
ORDER BY
    EE.IDUNIDAD
```

Comment: What is the error message/problem when you try? "It doesn't work" isn't a very exact description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) operator to pass a column to a table-valued function like that. In your case it would rather be OUTER APPLY than CROSS APPLY, to match your current outer join logic:

```
SELECT
    EE.IDEstatus, EE.IDAsignacion,EE.IDUNIDAD, 
    EE.IDEQUIPO,EE.ESTATUS,EE.bUltEstatus, 
    A.IDDestino, U.UbicacionF, TI.Tiempo 
FROM 
    dbo.mar_EstatusEquipo EE 
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.mar_Asignaciones A ON EE.IDAsignacion = A.IDAsignacion 
                       AND EE.IDUNIDAD = A.IDUNIDAD
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.mar_TmpUbicaciones U ON EE.IDUNIDAD = U.IdUnidad AND U.IdUnidad = A.IDUNIDAD
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT t.Tiempo
    FROM
        dbo.mar_TiemposArriboPto AS t
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Split(U.UbicacionF, ',', '1') AS s ON t.Ubicacion LIKE '%' + s.Value + '%'
) AS TI
WHERE 
    EE.IDEquipo = CAST(EE.IDUNIDAD AS CHAR)
    AND EE.Estatus IN ('IT','ET')
    AND A.IDDestino = 'MZO'
    AND EE.bUltEstatus = 1
    AND EE.IDUNIDAD = 255
ORDER BY
    EE.IDUNIDAD
;
```